# Flutter Text widget doesn't recognize some characters, shows "?" instead

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to display text using the Text widget but it's not displaying properly. It shows the "?" for characters it cannot read. How can I fix this?

This is the result I want.
[image]
And this is the error.
[image]

Comment: Share your code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally due to the special characters not being supported by the charset / font. Hence, rendering as questions marks. Try some other font that has all those characters / glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

That's should be using the default font for your app. If you see that is not working, you can always use a custom font that has "your_text".